# Getting error when retrieving iTunes Track Artwork image. Sometimes it says it's not an Image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, itunes

I have the following code to retrieve the currentTrack's artwork (using `iTunes.h`):

```
iTunesArtwork *iTunesArtwork = [[iTunes.currentTrack artworks] objectAtIndex:0];
NSImage *artwork = iTunesArtwork.data;                   
if (artwork != nil){
    [_musicImageView setImage:artwork];
}
```

It works for most of the tracks but sometimes it gives me this error (even when the track has an image):

```
NSImageCell's object value must be an NSImage.
2012-12-28 00:22:12.217 App[3256:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff904360a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d5bf3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90435e7c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff9747c31b -[NSImageCell setObjectValue:] + 106
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff974b8563 -[NSImageView setImage:] + 90
    5   App                                 0x0000000100001b38 -[AppDelegate setupPlayer] + 600
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d10c513 __NSFireTimer + 96
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff903f2da4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff903f28bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 557
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff903d8099 __CFRunLoopRun + 1513
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff903d76b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
    11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff939e40a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff939e3e42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff939e3cd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff97337613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff97336ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff9732e283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff972d2cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
    18  App                                 0x0000000100001822 main + 34
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff93cb77e1 start + 0
)
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure it is an image -- not just check if its not nil, thats not enough. the type in an h file must not be the type the object really has. It is more like... it SHOULD be an image :D

```
if([artwork isKindOfClass:[NSImage class]]) {
    ....
```

---

from the comments.
That didnt always work. ell. no more crashes but some images didnt show. we used the rawData as fallback:

```
//kind of like this
if(![artwork isKindOfClass:[NSImage class]]) {
    artwork = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:tunesArtwork.rawData];
}
if([artwork isKindOfClass:[NSImage class]]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man! this is really helpful! I've changed my code to look like this: http://pastebin.com/i56qQ6rr now I don't get any errors, as far as i've tested. But i'm having some issues with some tracks. The artwork is not presented in the nsimageview even when the artwork is available. do u know what's wrong?

Comment: sorry dont know what's up with those files. the linked code looks ok... except.. try to log the kind and find out what kind means what => e.g. 0=cover, 2=random, 3=dont_know or so.. oh and do the same for format.. maybe you can figure out why it doesnt work that way

Comment: i did that. I can't find a pattern with `kind` because there is always 0 or 3 and they work on both ways. But i figured it out what's wrong. The artwork doesn't appear only when the following is logged `Format <NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'PNG '>` it's definitely because of the `'PNG '` (the end space, or something like that). Any ideas on how to fix it?. If `Format <NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'JPEG'>` is logged the artwork is shown everytime.

Comment: try to make your own image from the rawData instead of using the provided one: `artwork=[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:tunesArtwork.rawData]`

Comment: @PedroVieira: The end space is not a problem. Those are four-character codes; spaces were almost always the go-to choice for padding out a type name that didn't naturally fill out four characters (although I remember 'PNGf' being the file type for PNGs back in the Mac OS days). One other thing: Switching to a for..in loop will make your loop code cleaner, and make the loop run (slightly) faster.